# How to prevent user from clicking mobile website

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been asked to try and implement the ability to lock the entire website down when a user is moving around.

I am not concerned at this point about figuring how to find if a user has moved, that is not important right now. We are just wondering if its possible to prevent a user from using a website or browser, and have it locked down.

We are being told it's possible with a Opera on Android, however we are not sure how to find information about this. When I use prevent interaction, or prevent click, i get a lot of other things.

Can someone tell us straight up, if this is possible. (We are essentially trying to stop users from using the ASP.NET MVC 4 application while they are moving. Once they stop moving, control should be returned.

Comment: what do u mean by "moving"?

Comment: An idea would be to have a div as cover which will absorb all the user interactions and will be the size of the size of the screen

Comment: Moving, as in GPS location has changed more than X within the last X seconds. Something like that. Although that solution is not the hard part, so I'm not concerned about this. It's easy to find out if the user moved. Not so easy to prevent interaction with mobile device though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add/remove this with javascript.  Of course, if you are looking for some more secure, you could do some server side checking with session variables, and redirect them based to a 403 page of some sort.

```
<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 100000;"></div>
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Ok so really these people were trying to make it sound like we would be able to prevent all browser functionality, not just page functionality. I suppose I will try this solution if they insist on having this feature, although it seems a bit overkill. If they are using the phone, they are using it already and are distracted. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Preventing browser functionality is not and never will be supported by any browser, without some sort of plugin.  If you are implementing something like a Firefox plugin, then this would be possible.  However if you are just making a website, then there is no possible way to prevent any kind of browser functionality.